# Telerik Form running as Dialog stuck sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-window

I'm using two RadTreeView to Drag and Drop Nodes from Right to Left. When "Node 1" is Drag from Right and Drop to Left RadTreeView a Dialog is shown.

If I Drag and Drop other Node before "Node 1" the Dialog stuck and I cannot write on the texboxes.

How can I solve this issue?

**Main Form**
[image: Main Form]

```
public partial class Main : RadForm
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RightRadTreeView_DragEnded(object sender, RadTreeViewDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Node.Text == "Node 1")
        {
            new RadForm1().ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Right
        this.RightRadTreeView.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode { Text = "Node 1" });
        this.RightRadTreeView.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode { Text = "Node 2" });
        this.RightRadTreeView.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode { Text = "Node 3" });
        this.RightRadTreeView.Nodes.Add(new RadTreeNode { Text = "Node 4" });


    }

}
```

**Dialog Form**

[image: Dialog Form]

```
   public partial class NewForm : Form
    {
        public NewForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void NewForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by "stuck"?

Comment: stuck means not allow me to write in this context.

Comment: Can you show code of dialog form? At least `Load` eventhandler, because something happens there, which can "stuck" a form

Comment: @Fabio I added the code form the Form that I'm using as dialog.